# ddwrt openwrt still in trend?

Tags: router

my old ddwrt router is funky and I want to get a new router for it. I checked most routers in the database seems to be either old models or old hardware version. Can any one recommend any models that are still reasonably easy to buy new and ddwrt/openwrt compatible? I do not want TP-Link or any brand that has heavy Chinese linkage.

Comment: rottenwifi.com has "5 Best Router For OpenWRT in 2022". Specifically, the Linksys WRT AC3200 "comes equipped with open-source firmware" apparently.

Comment: thanks @Stax just checked that article, most router are mid-high tier price range. I woulld want to see if there are mid-low tier price range. the previous ddwrt router I had was around price range of 60 USD

Comment: checked several online articles, most of the router recommended are either not available in amazon UK or quite very expensive without clearly stating the hardware version. Still no easy way of safely guaranteeing a successful ddwrt install.